# How to assign object validation in yup for react-select (single-select)

Tags: reactjs, react-select, formik, yup

I am trying to implement validation for react-select (single-select) using yup concept. But i am getting this error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {label, value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I want to know how to assign objects in validation schema for yup concept

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    department:"",
  }}
  onSubmit={this.submitForm}
  validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
    department: Yup.object().shape({
      label: Yup.string().required(),
      value: Yup.string().required(),
    }),
})}>
{ props => {
  const {
    values,
    touched,
    errors,
    isSubmitting,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    handleSubmit,
    selectedOption
  } = props;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>

    <InputLabel shrink htmlFor={'department'}>
    Department</InputLabel>
    <Select
          inputId="department"
          options={options}
          value={values.department}
          onChange={this.onChangeOption}
          onBlur={handleBlur}         
       />
{errors.department && touched.department && ( {errors.department} )} 
Submit </div> </React.Fragment> ); }}
```

Comment: Is this approach working.stuck at same place

Answer (score 24):

> I want to know how to assign objects in validation schema for yup concept

You did it correct (as far as I can tell):

```
validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
  department: Yup.object().shape({
    label: Yup.string().required(),
    value: Yup.string().required(),
  })
}
```

What React complains about is this line:

```
{errors.department && touched.department && ( {errors.department} )}
```

What this evalautes to is if `errors` has a key called `department` and if `touched` has a key called `department` then render the object `errors.department`. React can't do that. If you want to display the errors you I suggest having a dedicated component (e.g. a `<p>` tag) for it outside of your select. Something like this:

```
{errors.department && touched.department && (<p>{errors.department.label}</p>)}
```

You can do something similar for `value`.

PS: Your code seems incomplete and poorly formatted (e.g. there is a floating `<div />` tag).

Answer (score 3):

You can refine the shape schema with `nullable()` and `required()`.

Example

```
const requiredOption = Yup.object()
  .shape({
    value: Yup.string(),
    label: Yup.string(),
  })
  .nullable()
  .required('This field is required.');
```

Why `nullable()` and `required()` to the shape!

1. If an input is focused and the user decides to skip the input, a value for that input is still set to null and the validation is triggered. Eventually, you would end up with an error like this.

> input must be an `object` type, but the final value was: `null`. If
> "null" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as
> `.nullable()`

2. Instead of having required on individual properties of shape schema, if you are sure all the properties are mandatory, the required function can be called on the object shape directly.

Comment: thanks. in my case I only had to add `.nullable()` after `required()` and it works

Answer (score 1):

Little tweak from above comment of Hesters.

```
    validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        valueToBeChange: Yup.object().shape({
           label: Yup.string().required('label is required'),
           value: Yup.string().required('value is required'),
        })
     }
```

On the front end I have added condition

```
    (valueToBeChange?.label?.message && valueToBeChange?.label?.message) 
&& (valueToBeChange?.value?.message && valueToBeChange?.value?.message)
```

Answer (score 1):

> For using multiple items in a single object it must be assigned like this

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  salaryDept: Yup.object().shape({
    employee: Yup.string().required("Field Required"),
    amount: Yup.string().required("Field Required"),
    deduction: Yup.string().required("Field Required"),
      })
 });
```

> in Formik pass validationSchema you just created as follows:

```
<Formik
  validationSchema={validationSchema}
> </Formik>
```

> and Now the error messages you want to show which is as follows:

```
helperText={
 errors.salaryDept?.employee &&
 touched.salaryDept?.employee &&
 errors.salaryDept?.employee}
 error={
 errors.salaryDept?.employee &&
 touched.salaryDept?.employee
 }
```